# Empty UITextField 0

Tags: swift, calculator

I am working on height convertor that converts height in feet and inches into centimeters.

The program essentially has 2 UITextFields, one labelled feet and the other inches. The user enters the number into each textfield, hits calculate, and the height is converted into centimeters.

Currently if either textfield is empty, no calculation is performed. I am assuming that I need to give an empty textfield the value of 0 so that the calculation is performed, but I can't seem to figure out how to do this.

This is my current code for this section:

```
@IBAction func Calculate1Button(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let generator = UINotificationFeedbackGenerator()
    generator.notificationOccurred(.success)
    
    if let feetToCm = Double(feetToCmTextField.text!) {
        let feetToCmValue = Double(feetToCm * 30.48)
        if let inchesToCm = Double(inchesToCmTextField.text!) {
            let inchesToCmValue = Double(inchesToCm * 2.54)
            let result1 = Int(feetToCmValue + inchesToCmValue)
            
            result1Label.text = " \(result1) cm"
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `if let` when trying to get a `Double` value for the two text fields, you can fallback to a value of 0.

```
@IBAction func Calculate1Button(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let generator = UINotificationFeedbackGenerator()
    generator.notificationOccurred(.success)

    // Assume "0 ft" if no value or an invalid value        
    let feetToCm = Double(feetToCmTextField.text!) ?? 0.0
    // Assume "0 in" if no value or an invalid value        
    let inchesToCm = Double(inchesToCmTextField.text!) ?? 0.0
    let feetToCmValue = feetToCm * 12 * 2.54
    let inchesToCmValue = inchesToCm * 2.54
    let result1 = Int(feetToCmValue + inchesToCmValue)
    result1Label.text = " \(result1) cm"
}
```

A few notes:

1. This has nothing to do with SwiftUI
2. Function names (along with variable names and case names) should begin with lowercase letters. Class, struct, and enum names begin with uppercase letters.
3. Note that there is no need to convert a `Double` result into a `Double`. For example, you had  `let inchesToCmValue = Double(inchesToCm * 2.54)` when it only needs to be `let inchesToCmValue = inchesToCm * 2.54` since `inchesToCmValue` is already a `Double`.

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply on this, but only just had a chance to sit down and do some work on this... Your solution has worked beautifully, thank you! And also thank you for the tips as well. Very new to this so learning as I go!